# On Stinespring's Theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, density-operator, open-quantum-systems

Wherein the proof of Stinespring's theorem does complete positivity enter? Suppose my map is not completely positive but the Kraus operators follow the trace preservation condition as 
$\sum_{n = 1}^{m}K_{n}^\dagger K_{n} - \sum_{n = m+1}^{d^2}K_{n}^\dagger K_{n} = 1$, can't a Stinespring unitary still be constructed? Is complete positivity necessary? Kindly advise on the same.